# Div table sort control / ordering using react

Tags: reactjs, redux, lodash

I have a table created from `</div>`'s, each row is mapped onto what would be a "table header" `</th>` but that is also a div table. The rows are mapped and belong to there own component. I want to be able to click on the table header and it sorts the mapped rows by desc and asc.

I'm not sure how to do this because A: the rows are mapped and needs to relate back to the headers on the other view and B: its not a traditional table - I'm using divs. I am using react with redux, lodash and various other libraries.

Here is a simple working example with code of what I have: https://codesandbox.io/s/842roor210

```js
<React.Fragment>
  <div class="contact-item ripple row no-gutters align-items-center py-2 px-3 py-sm-4 px-sm-6">
    <div className="col px-1 text-truncate font-weight-bold text-uppercase">
      Name
    </div>
    <div className="col text-truncate px-1 d-none d-lg-flex font-weight-bold text-uppercase">
      Durability
    </div>
    <div className="col text-truncate px-1 d-none d-lg-flex font-weight-bold text-uppercase">
      Speed
    </div>
    <div className="col text-truncate px-1 font-weight-bold text-uppercase">
      Fitness
    </div>
    {coachReport.player.map((player, i) => (
      <CoachReportRow
        key={i}
        firstname={player.firstName}
        lastname={player.lastName}
        durabilityscore={player.durabilityScore}
        speed={player.speed}
        fitness={player.fitness}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
</React.Fragment>;
```

then

```js
const CoachReportRow = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="col-12 contact-item ripple row no-gutters align-items-center py-2 px-3 py-sm-2 px-sm-6">
        <div className="col px-1 text-truncate">
          {props.firstname} {props.lastname}
        </div>
        <div className="col px-1 text-truncate">{props.durabilityscore}</div>
        <div className="col px-1 text-truncate">{props.speed}</div>
        <div className="col px-1 text-truncate">{props.fitness}</div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Introduce a prop `sort` with the shape `{field,direction}` to the table component. As your row component is only responsible for rendering one row, it should not be concerned with actually sorting anything. So you would need to do the sorting of the actual data before you map over it. Do the sorting based on the values of the `sort` prop.

Comment: @hazardous example snippet and question author about sorting data: https://codesandbox.io/s/jmv6y877w

Comment: @hazardous So its now sorted as per andy-theos example, but surely if I now wanted the header to act like a button to switch between asc and desc I would have to be concerned with the rows?

Comment: So you `sort` props can be used to seed the initial internal sort `state`. Then the asc/desc buttons will simply change sort state. `render` will be invoked again and the data order will be done accordingly. Basically the whole react deal :).